# C# Sort List according to another List values

Tags: c#, list, sorting

I need to sort one list (string) according to another list values (int) from the smallest to the highest int.
Possibility to have several times the same string.

For example:

```
List<string> list1= new List<string>() { "abc", "xyzz", "abc", "fgh", "abc" };

List<int> list2 = new List<int>() { 8, 15, 4, 2, 22 };
```

output:

```
list1 {"fgh","abc", "abc", "xyzz", "abc"}
```

This line should probably work but I still miss something:

```
list1 = list1.OrderBy(d => list2."i miss something here".ToList());
```

Comment: It's not clear what you are trying to do. How would you like your list2 to affect the ordering of list1?

Comment: from the smallest int to the highest int , put in order

Comment: the first int determines the first string, second int second string and so on.

Comment: abc is represented by 8, xyzz 15, abc 4, fgh 2, abc 22, then in order from smallest to highest: fgh, abc, abc, xyzz, abc

Comment: I could use a dictionary and do it easily with this:   foreach (KeyValuePair<string, int> author in dict1.OrderBy(key => key.Value))
            {
                list1.Add(author.Key);
            }   Problem is dictionary can't have twice the same key. Therefore I decided to use two lists for that purpose.

Comment: Something like `list1.Select((x, i) => (Item: x, Index: i)).OrderBy(t => list2[t.Index]).Select(t => t.Item).ToList()` ought to work. In any case, see duplicates...there are lots of examples on the site already you can draw from.

Comment: What Peter Duniho just suggested is working well. This resolves the question.

Comment: It might worked, but is not the best. Use this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/13144084/5202563 by Servy based on `Zip`